# 自作ステガノグラフィのコードについて

Tags: python, pillow, 画像処理

## コードの概要

LSBステガノグラフィのコードをpythonで書いています。
各ピクセルのRGBデータのLSBに、任意の文字列の2進数1bitずつを、入れるようなコードにしています。

## 困っていること

文字列の2進数を各RGBのLSBに入れるところまでできました。
しかし、文字列を入れた画像を出力して、再度読み込むと、期待した値を取り出すことができません。

元の画像データと文字列を入力した画像の大きさを比べると、約0.5MBも異なりました。

エンコードするときの品質が関係しているのかなぁ？と予想していますが、何が原因かわかりません。

## 実際の実行結果

画像に文字列を入れるときの、処理のデバッグ↓
0
original 128
binary original 10000000
pass_num 0
no changed

---

1
original 121
binary original 01111001
pass_num 1
no changed

---

2
original 135
binary original 10000111
pass_num 1
no changed

---

3
original 99
binary original 01100011
pass_num 1
no changed

---

出力した画像を、再度取得したときの値

0
123
1
123
2
135
3
92

LSBだけを変更するので、最大でも1しか変わらないはずです。

どこがおかしいのか、ご指摘お願いします。

## ソースコード

```
# # 画像を読み込み、RGBの値を10進数で出力
# 

# In[11]:


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #画像を表示するためのモジュール
import cv2  #OpenCVをインポート
import numpy as np #numpyをインポート
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
 
img_ = Image.open("r25_sakura.jpg")
img_ = img_.convert('RGB')
print(type(img_))
img_array = np.asarray(img_) #numpyで扱える配列をつくる

print(img_array.shape)

plt.imshow(img_array)
plt.show()


# # 入力したいパスワードを2進数に変換

# In[3]:


pass_string = input("パスワードを入力してください  >>  ")
#ordで文字のunicodeを返す。　そのunicodeを8bitの2進数に戻す。

binary_representation = ''.join(format(ord(char), '08b') for char in pass_string)
#0000000000000000は終了コード
binary_representation = binary_representation+"0000000000000000"
print(binary_representation)


# # パスワードを画像の中に入れる関数を書く。
# ## RGBの中のRだけを今回は使う。

# In[4]:


#pic_RGB_numはRGBの値
#pass_numはパスワードを2進数にした1つの値
def password_in_picture(pic_RGB_num , pass_num):
    binary_pic_RGB_num = format(pic_RGB_num , '08b')
    print("original" , pic_RGB_num)
    print("binary original" , binary_pic_RGB_num)
    print("pass_num", pass_num)
    # LSBが1で、pass_numが0の場合、LSBを0に変更
    if(int(binary_pic_RGB_num[7]) == 1 and int(pass_num) == 0):
        print("int(binary_pic_RGB_num[7]) == 1 and int(pass_num) == 0")
        print("changed binary" , format(pic_RGB_num -1 , '08b'))
        print("changed " , pic_RGB_num -1)
        print("***************")
        return pic_RGB_num -1
    # LSBが0で、pass_numが1の場合、LSBを1に変更
    elif(int(binary_pic_RGB_num[7]) == 0 and int(pass_num) == 1):
        print("int(binary_pic_RGB_num[7]) == 0 and int(pass_num) == 1")
        print("changed binary" , format(pic_RGB_num +1 , '08b'))
        print("changed " , pic_RGB_num +1)
        print("***************")
        return pic_RGB_num +1
    # LSBとpass_numが同じの場合、変更せずreturn
    print("no changed")
    print("*****************")
    return pic_RGB_num


# In[10]:


pass_idx = 0
# 画像の中のRGBすべてをなめる
for row_ in range(img_array.shape[0]):
    for col_ in range(img_array.shape[1]):
        for color_idx in range(3):
            if(pass_idx < len(binary_representation)):
                print(pass_idx)
                img_array[row_,col_ ,color_idx]=password_in_picture(img_array[row_ , col_ , color_idx] , binary_representation[pass_idx])
                pass_idx+=1


# # 実際にパスワードを注入した画像が以下

# In[6]:


plt.imshow(img_array)
plt.show()
# numpyからPIL.Image.Imageに変更
img_ = Image.fromarray(img_array)
img_.save("r25_result.jpg")


# # 画像から文字列を取得する

# In[7]:


#画像から、文字列を取得する。

img_ = Image.open("r25_result.jpg")

pass_img = np.asarray(img_)

print(pass_img.shape)

plt.imshow(pass_img)
plt.show()


# In[8]:


def get_password_from_picture(num_in_pic):
    binary_in_pass = format(num_in_pic , '08b')
    print(num_in_pic)
    return int(binary_in_pass[7])


# In[9]:


pass_str = [] # 画像内に入っている2進数を入れるリスト
null_flag = 0 # 0の個数を数えるための変数
num =0  # 何週回ったのか、カウントのための変数

for row_ in range(pass_img.shape[0]):
    if null_flag == 16:
        break
    for col_ in range(pass_img.shape[1]):
        if null_flag == 16:
            break
        for color_idx in range(3):
            print(num)
            lsb_ = get_password_from_picture(pass_img[row_, col_, color_idx])
            pass_str.append(lsb_)
            num+=1
            if lsb_ == 0:
                null_flag += 1
            else:
                null_flag = 0
            
            if null_flag == 16:
                break


# # 取り出したバイナリデータを、8個ずつに分けて文字にする。

# In[14]:


#取り出したバイナリデータを、8個ずつに分けて文字にする。
import pprint
pass_lists = [pass_str[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(pass_str), 8)]
pprint.pprint(pass_lists)


# ##
```

Comment: 感想ですが、JPEGのような不可逆圧縮で画素の下位1bitがそのまま生き残る確率は低そうです。

Comment: なるほど、、、確かにそうですね。pngですべきでした。　盲点でした、、、、

Answer (score 3, accepted):

png形式で処理を行うと、期待した値が取り出せました。

ありがとうございました。